# Pure Javascript modal not posting via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html

Newbie javascript programmer so please bear with me here.

I'm developing a basic modal for a consent form in PURE JavaScript. Program flow is as follows:

1) The modal appears on page load.

2)When the user clicks the accept button, the value 'accept' should be POSTed via XMLHttpRequest and the css rule .modal display: block should change to .modal display: none (to remove the modal).

Now the problem that I am facing is that when the user clicks the accept button, the modal disappears as expected (so the css rule is changed to none) but the XMLHttpRequest is not posted.

My Code is as follows:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the Accept button
var acceptbtn = document.getElementById("accept-btn");

// Get the Decline button
var declinebtn = document.getElementById("decline-btn");

// Get the form
var consentform = document.getElementById("consent-form");

// When the Page Loads, open the modal 
window.onload = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks Accept button, close the modal and submit POST via xml
acceptbtn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/CapturePostedData/", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  xhr.send("agree=accept");
}
```

I have tried to solve this to the best of my current knowledge but am stuck.

Any help would be very much appreciated thank you in advance.
Regards Mike,

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1:8000` also the address you load the page from?

Comment: @Tomalak no its loaded from another webserver @ 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: You can't do Ajax communication with a different webserver, that's a security feature. Read up on the "Same-Origin Policy". (There are ways around this limitation, that will follow from reading a bit deeper into the topic.)

Comment: Oh, that is something i didnt know. Thanks for clearing that up i'll look into it right away.

Comment: It's an FAQ and a very common stumbling block for webdev beginners. (Your browser's developer console will show an error entry for the failed Ajax request, too. Always look there first when something does not work.)